# Colours different when testing against iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, uistoryboard

I'm making an iOS app using Autolayout and Universal devices. Everything works fine on both devices except for one thing, colours. I change the colours directly form the storyboard so I don't know why this happens:

Here is a iPhone screenshot, and an iPad screenshot of the same view:

[image: iPhone view]
[image: iPad view]

I had some colours which were set to default in the storyboard, but even after setting them it's not perfect:

[image: iPad view after some changes of default cl]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work with any cell, accessory view or not, you have to add this function in your controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 42/255, blue: 43/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the background color for a `UITableView` you have to create a background view and assign it to the `tableView.backgroundView` property. So, in `viewDidLoad` of your viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()  // just to demonstrate        
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing that. But why does that work on iPhone and not on iPad?

Comment: I cannot say what causes the effect you get, would need to see your storyboard. The above code should work anyway.

Comment: This helped, even though I changed it from the storyboard, but it wasn't working for the accessory.